# sent ping but didn't receive pong within 1000ms in jenkins

Tags: automation, jenkins-groovy, socket-timeout-exception

when running a jenkins pipeline job, there sometimes a sockettimeout error.
"sent ping but didn't receive pong within 1000ms in jenkins",

i have checked blog like this, but there is no specific answer for such a question.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53532?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel